# Vue Dynamic Component Ordering?

Tags: vue.js

Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm using the Vue's dynamic component tag in an application.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

The component list is provided via a computed property which I simply iterate over creating `<component />` elements.

```
<component v-for="component in myComponents" :key="component" is="component />
```

The issue i'm running into is the components are loaded asynchronously and some components can take longer at times than others to load. Due to this sometimes the components load out of the desired order.

I was curious if anyone had a suggestion on how I might be able to force the components to display in a desired order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use an ordered computed property, for exemple if you want to order your components by name.

In the template :

```
<component v-for="component in orderedComponents" :key="component" is="component />
```

In the script

```
computed: {
  orderedComponents: function () {
    return _.orderBy(this.myComponents, 'name')
  }
}
```

This exemple is using Lodash but of course you can order it the way you want.

You can check the documentation : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter

Comment: Please read carefully on the OP's question: `...the components are loaded asynchronously and some components can take longer at times than others to load`. So the problem is not so much about how to simply order these dynamic components.

Comment: Your answer put me on the right track. I ended up adding an order property to the json object i use that gets added to the component list. then i used the computed property you mention to order by that order property. works like a charm... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can enforce the order by setting :key to a number.

First, modify your for loop to use indexes:

```
v-for="(index, value) in myComponents"
```

Then set key to the index

```
:key="index"
```

This should keep the order in tact - if it doesn't, you could always create placeholders first then replace them in the runtime.